# Media player framework WinRT, label showing info how to remove?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, media-player, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows 8.1 and i am using the playerFramework:MediaPlayer from codeplex (https://playerframework.codeplex.com/) and when I put my cursor on the seek bar or the timer i have a label that appears on the player.  I have tried to play around with the style but have not found a way to remove this, has anyone been able to remove this label?

Here is my XAML Player code:

```
<playerFramework:MediaPlayer
                            x:Name="Player"
                            Height="281"
                            Width="498"
                            IsCaptionSelectionVisible="False"
                            IsFullScreenEnabled="True"
                            IsFullScreenVisible="True"
                            IsPlayPauseVisible="True"
                            IsResolutionIndicatorVisible="False"
                            IsSignalStrengthVisible="False"
                            IsSkipAheadVisible="False"
                            IsSkipBackVisible="False"
                            IsTimeElapsedVisible="True"
                            IsTimeRemainingVisible="True"
                            IsTrickPlayEnabled="False"
                            IsVolumeVisible="True"
                            SeekWhileScrubbing="True"
                            ThumbnailImageSource="{Binding
                                VideoDetails.Thumbnail480Uri,
                                Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}}" />
```

[image]

Comment: You say you've played around with the Style, but I'm sure there's templates embedded in there at multiple levels, is there some place in the docs with style templates we could go look (I didn't see them) or could you post something of them? Looks like you're looking for a Tooltip somewhere, it's just a matter of finding it.

Comment: I was more looking for something called label, ill try tooltip tomorrow thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, after looking at the playerFramework:MediaPlayer style I found the element that shows the tips.  This element is called Info, so i need to hide it.  So basically you need to added  IsInfoEnabled="False" to your MediaElement.

thus:

```
   <playerFramework:MediaPlayer
                    x:Name="Player"
                    MinHeight="281"
                    MinWidth="498"       
                    IsInfoEnabled="False"
                    ThumbnailImageSource="{Binding
                        Thumbnail480Uri,
                        Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}}"/>
```